# How do i divide an array into subarrays each a set of 5 elements and apply a separate class to elements in each subarray

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have set of "n" "li" elements. I want to divide the below list in a "x" subsets using jquery so that each subset has 5 "li" elements. Also, would want to apply different class to each subset 
e.g

```
<ul>
 <li>text1</li>
 <li>text1</li>
  ...
 ......
 <li>text1</li>
 <li>text1</li>
</ul>
```

subset 1

```
<li class="sebset1"></li>
<li class="sebset1"></li>
<li class="sebset1"></li>
<li class="sebset1"></li>
<li class="sebset1"></li>
```

subset 2

```
<li class="sebset2"></li>
<li class="sebset2"></li>
<li class="sebset2"></li>
<li class="sebset2"></li>
<li class="sebset2"></li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```js
let subsetNumber =0;

$('ul li').each(function(i)
{
    if(i %5 ==0)
   {
    subsetNumber++;
   }
   $(this).addClass( "sebset" + subsetNumber);   
});
```

```css
.sebset1{
color:red;
}

.sebset2{
color:green;
}

.sebset3{
color:blue;
}
.sebset4{
color:black;
}
.sebset5{
color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
 <li>text1</li>
 <li>text2</li>
 <li>text3</li>
 <li>text4</li>
 <li>text5</li>
 <li>text6</li>
 <li>text7</li>
 <li>text8</li>
 <li>text9</li>
 <li>text10</li>
 <li>text11</li>
 <li>text12</li>
 <li>text13</li>
 <li>text14</li>
 <li>text15</li>
 <li>text16</li>
 <li>text17</li>
 <li>text18</li>
 <li>text19</li>
 
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or in js:

```js
let j = 1;
[...document.querySelectorAll('li')].forEach((li, i) => {
  li.classList.add("sebset" +j);
  if(i !== 0 && (i+1) % 5 === 0) j++;
})

console.log([...document.querySelectorAll('li')])
```

```html
<ul>
   <li>text1</li>
   <li>text1</li>
   <li>text1</li>
   <li>text1</li>
   <li>text1</li>
   <li>text1</li>
   <li>text1</li>
   <li>text1</li>
   <li>text1</li>
   <li>text1</li>
   <li>text1</li>
   <li>text1</li>
</ul>
```